# tutorial using gstreamer for saving photos and videos from web cam

Tags: gtk, gstreamer

I know that i have to use gstreamer for creating an application to capture photo and videos

from web cam. But, i could not find any documentation describing vividly the steps for creating the

same. It will be very pleased,if any one could helped me in this.

Regards,
iSight

Answer (score 1):

There is a GNOME/vala tutorial in the work that shows you how to make a Gtk application to grab pictures:
https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/3.10/magic-mirror.vala.html.en

Saving a video is left for you to do, you'll have to use a [tee](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-tee.html) to have both live preview and recording simultaneously.

Also, there is a high-level object, [camerabin](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-plugins/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-camerabin.html), for your case, but I never used it myself.

Camerabin is being used by [libcheese](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-announce-list/2011-January/msg00075.html), that is even higher level and depends on Clutter (but not Gtk), and allows you to [plug effects with cheese_camera_set_effect()](http://git.gnome.org/browse/cheese/tree/libcheese/cheese-camera.h).

Pick what you need!

Comment: A working URL to magic-mirror now is https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/3.10/magic-mirror.vala.html.en